# Запись в БД на php без форм

Tags: php

Есть список, состоящий из слов. Могу ли я с помощью php записать слова из списка в БД?

---

Условная html разметка следующая:

- первый
- второй

Я хотел бы записать слова "первый" и "второй" в БД по клику на кнопку. Каждое слово в отдельную строчку. Как записать несколько строчек за раз я могу представить, а как сделать запись содержимого тега, не формы, к сожалению, нет. В сети находил инфу только по работе с формами.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Какой список? Какие слова из списка БД?

Comment: @doox911 Условная html разметка следующая:

первый

второй

Я хотел бы записать слова "первый" и "второй" в БД по клику на кнопку. Каждое слово в отдельную строчку. Как записать несколько строчек за раз я могу представить, а как сделать запись содержимого тега, не формы, к сожалению, нет. В сети находил инфу только по работе с формами.

Comment: В приведённых ниже ответах, есть решение вашего вопроса? Если да, то выберите его как решение.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш html. Можно и php файл сделать.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Тест</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my_block">
            <p class="text">Первый второй</p>
        </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(.text).on('click', function(){
                let text = $(this).text();
                let url = post.php
                $.post(url,text,function(data) {
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ваш php (вытаскиваешь данные из $_POST и делай с ними всё, что угодно):

```
if(isset($_POST['text']&&!empty($_POST['text'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
}else{
    // Действие если не существует или пусто
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте следующие:

На кнопки вешаете

```
<div onclick="javascript:send('Первый');">Первый</div>
<div onclick="javascript:send('Второй');">Второй</div>
```

добавляете скрипт

```
function send(text) {
    var idtext = text;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sendMYSQL.php',
        data: "idtext=" + idtext,
        success: function(result) {
        }
    })
}
```

И сам файл sendMYSQL.php

```
<? if(isset($_POST["idtext"])) 
{ 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'test';
$dbpass = 'test';
$dbname = 'test';
$connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8");

$idtext = $_POST['idtext'];
$result = "insert into tablica(text)value('$idtext')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $result); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Используйте драйвер [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @doox911 зачем pdo? Можно и mysqli.